# Dynamic loading of external library fails

Tags: javascript, d3.js, iframe

I have an iframe within another document where I want to put a D3 animation. As I don't have access to the main page's files I load the src dynamically.

The thing is, if I have an alert() between function that loads the library and function that uses it everything works fine. But without it (which is what I'm after) I get the console error that d3 is unknown.

I tried putting the d3Check() in window.onload, I tried to put it in setTimeout but no luck.

Why is this happening and how to make it run smoothly, without alerts?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click me"/>

<script>

function d3Load() {
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    jsElm.type = "text/javascript";
    jsElm.src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js";
    jsElm.charset = "utf-8";
    document.head.appendChild(jsElm);
//debugger;
};
//debugger;

function d3Check() {
var a = d3.select("body");
alert("good");
};

d3Load();
alert();
d3Check();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the `src` attribute of `jsElem`, the source will be loaded asynchronously in the background, so you may want to wait for the loading to finish until you proceed. This can be done using the `onload` attribute of the `script` tag:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click me"/>

<script>

function d3Load() {
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    jsElm.type = "text/javascript";
    jsElm.src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js";
    jsElm.charset = "utf-8";
    jsElm.onload = d3Check;
    document.head.appendChild(jsElm);
};


function d3Check() {
var a = d3.select("body");
alert("good");
};

d3Load();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the very same result.  I applied the importScript you mentioned and it loads the library into the <head> correctly, but it fails to use it. With alert() in between loading and using - again all works fine. I also tried to force the code to wait 5 secs befor trying to apply it, but it seems without me clicking on the alert it just doesn't load

Comment: @Zenon, I added a code snippet detailing volzo's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the script's load event before trying to use any of the methods it contains.

```
jsElm.onload = d3Check();
```

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts)